# ImageMagick's mogrify tool darkens PNGs (when only trying to resize)

Tags: linux, imagemagick, png, image-editing, mogrify

I'm trying to use the simple command to resize images and overwrite the originals:

```
mogrify -resize 80% *
```

My source images are semi-transparent PNGs that happen to be grayscale. The resize operation works, but is making the images darker.

[image]

This used to work on a different machine (Ubuntu 12.04, with `ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06`) and has broken on a newer machine (Ubuntu 14.04, with `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06`). As of this posting, the broken version is the latest version in the Ubuntu 14.04 repos.

Since ImageMagick is a scriptable tool, this is an unfortunate regression that should have been caught by a unit test. I'm off to check my scripted image workflows.

FYI - apparently the convert tool is also affected.

Comment: Try to add `-type truecolorAlpha` ([check here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21436))

Comment: Yes, the `-type truecolorAlpha` option also appears to workaround the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `-type truecolorAlpha` can solve this problem.

It's possible to [find an explanation](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21436) related with the kind of truecolor PNG of the original file and the different palette size before and after the resizing operation.

Essentially it was  a bug  from a wrong recognition of an iCCP profile from PNG (colortype 6) that was recognised as sRGB, and can occur in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [blog post](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/746) showing a workaround by specifying the format of the output. For me, I wanted semi-transparent PNGs, so the best choice was to add the `-define png:format=png32` option:

```
mogrify -define png:format=png32 -resize 80% *
```

(The blog suggests `-define png:format=png24` but that appears to limit output alpha to 1-bit.)